# Vibrate during the day, ringer on at night automatically

Tags: ios, do-not-disturb

I want my phone to be on vibrate all day, but allow all phone calls to go through at night. This is the opposite of the way it seems DND is intended to work.

I can't do a reverse version of DND (DND during the day) because it kills the vibrate feature.

I need to get calls overnight for work, but I don't want to have to remember every single night to flip the switch on my phone. How can I accomplish this on iOS?

I am currently on version 14.8 (18H17) running on a 12 pro max.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you running?

Comment: 14.8 (18H17).  I have a 12 pro max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try a custom ringtone...?

I would recommend creating a custom ringtone that has silence for the first X seconds, then rings however you'd prefer.  This would allow you to answer/ignore any calls you feel coming in via vibration, while not making any ring sound for the first X seconds.  Then you can leave your phone's ringer on all the time.

The only caveat is that once you hear your ringer, you'll only have 24-X seconds left to answer it.

Feel free to adjust those timings as you see fit, of course.

Alternatively, you could also use a custom ringtone that starts quietly, then gets louder.  Same idea, but audible throughout the ring.

Also, a combination of the above could also be employed.

Btw, I believe Garage Band will allow you to make ringtones if you don't have any other options.

Comment: It's so disappointing how often simple little features like this aren't implemented by Apple. But thank you for the creative suggestion.. this is probably what I will end up doing.